# Blender 2.79 How to make an animation of a moving trembling hand?

Tags: animation

I want to create a trembling arm.
But while it trembles, I want to move it up/down/rigt/left.
How to achive this?

Comment: go to Graph editor > Properties (N) > Modifiers tab and add noise modifier to f-curve

Comment: Ok, I manage to do it, but, the tremble is so fast and constant. 
Ho to make it slow but sometimes fast

Comment: With a mouse howering above any noise parameter you can press i key to add keyframes to animate a value - so it become !aster or slower.